# Shell Script - Get name of dynamically generated file

Tags: regex, file, shell

I'm very new to shell script and therefore I don't now very much about it.
I have an application, which creates a java file with a half unknown name, and now I try to write a script, which needs this name.
The known name of the file is `/target/plugin-<dyn>.jar`, the `<dyn>` part is unknown and could be nearly anything (btw it is mostly a version number with variable text parts).
Now I want to save `plugin-<dyn>` (without the `.jar`) in a variable for later use. I looked very much in the internet, but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need get file name without extension `.jar`. You can refer my bash script below:

```
# for loop all files in target directory that matched plugin-*.jar
for f in target/plugin-*.jar
do 
    # print file name without extension .jar
    echo ${f%.*}
done
```

**UPDATED:**

```
# for loop all files in target directory that matched plugin-*.jar
for f in target/plugin-*.jar
do 
    # print file name without extension .jar
    filename="${f##*/}" # get plugin-*.jar
    echo ${filename%.*} # print plugin-* without jar
done
```

Comment: need to add `shopt -s nullglob` for a case nothing matched.

Comment: This also returns the path, `./target/` but I only need the file name

Comment: I found a solution, first go with cd into the directory and after it I go with cd back to the parent directory

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
filename="/target/plugin-<dyn>.jar"
echo ${filename} | awk -F [/.] '{print $(NF - 1)}'
echo ${filename} | sed 's/.*\/\([^/]*\)\.jar/\1/'
```

but if `<dyn>` has a slash, comma or point. it may not work